# SceneKit Scene Incorrect Size

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I have a SceneKit iOS game I'm setting up, and when `didMoveToView` is called, the scene height is `768.0` (according to `self.size.height`).

If I use this number and divide it by two, I do **not** get the vertical center of the screen.

I then use `touchesBegan` to trigger events after `didMoveToView`. Both according to the `touches` event passed as well as according to `self.size.height` at this point, the screen is `375.0` tall.

What gives?, and how can I get the correct height in `didMoveToView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scene you have access to the view.  You should call

```
self.scene.size = view.bounds.size;
```

immediately after didMoveToView.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the vertical center of the screen by using `CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)`
but dividing the screen by two should work...